# JMS & Spring Integration, removing the dependency on having a ActiveMQ instance

Tags: java, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I recently set up some logging to AcitveMQ as a fire and forget service so that the application can just send a message to an "ActivityLoggingChannel" and not have to deal with the cross cutting concerns of logging.

Everything is sent to the ActivityLoggingGateway which is just an interface with a default channel. This then queries a Pojo (dyanmic router) for a channel name to get the message end point. There is a JMX entry point to the dynamic router which allows me to switch end points on the fly. If the message end point is set to jmsChannelSender and it cannot resolve the ActiveMQ url, it will cause the whole system to fall over.

The problem I'm having is that if the ActiveMQ URL is not reachable I would like the system to revert to a different message channel which uses a simple multi-threaded in process approach.

Here is the spring integration configuration below. Using version 2.0.0.RELEASE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms"
    xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jms/spring-integration-jms-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/stream/spring-integration-stream-2.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="dm-activitylogging-services.xml"/>

    <bean name="decisionActivityLoggingAspect" class="com.idna.dm.aspects.logging.activity.DecisionActivityLogAspect" 
        factory-method="aspectOf">
        <property name="activityLoggingGateway">
            <ref bean="activityLoggingGateway" />
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- New Activity Logging Services Reference dm-activity-logging -->    
<!-- JMS Channel Adapter -->
    <int:channel id="jmsSenderChannel" />

    <bean id="destinationLocalQueue" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="${activemq.queuename.activitylogging}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="${activemq.url}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="activityLogConverter" class="com.idna.dm.domain.activitylogging.jms.ActivityLogConverter" />
    <jms:outbound-channel-adapter channel="jmsSenderChannel"  destination="destinationLocalQueue" connection-factory="connectionFactory" message-converter="activityLogConverter"/>

<!--  In Process Adapter -->

    <int:channel id="inProcessChannel" />   
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="inProcessChannel" ref="inProcessAdapter" method="persistLog" />
    <bean id="inProcessAdapter" class="com.idna.dm.logging.activity.impl.InProcessActivityLoggingImpl" >
        <property name="activityLoggingService" >
            <ref bean="activityLogging" />
        </property>
    </bean>

    <int:channel id="asyncInProcessChannel" />
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="asyncInProcessChannel" ref="asyncInProcessAdapter" method="persistLog" />
    <bean id="asyncInProcessAdapter" class="com.idna.dm.logging.activity.impl.AsyncInProcessActivityLoggingImpl" >
        <property name="activityLoggingService">
            <ref bean="activityLogging" />
        </property>
    </bean>

<!-- Custom channel for console output using the router -->

    <!-- Console Channel 
    <int:channel id="consoleAdapterChannel" />
    <int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="consoleAdapterChannel" ref="consoleAdapter" method="printToStdout" />
    <bean id="consoleAdapter" class="com.idna.dm.logging.activity.util.StdoutTargetAdapter" />
     -->

    <!-- Log4j Channel -->
    <int:channel id="loggingChannel" />
    <int:logging-channel-adapter auto-startup="true" level="INFO" log-full-message="true" channel="loggingChannel" />

<!-- Router -->
    <int:gateway id="activityLoggingGateway" 
        service-interface="com.idna.dm.logging.activity.logger.ActivityLoggingGateway" />


    <int:channel id="activityLoggingChannel" />

    <int:router input-channel="activityLoggingChannel" ref="dynamicRouter"
        method="route" default-output-channel="asyncInProcessChannel"
        ignore-channel-name-resolution-failures="true" />

    <bean id="dynamicRouter" class="com.idna.dm.logging.activity.router.DynamicRouter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="asyncInProcessChannel" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: Good idea, so what's the question?

Comment: Sorry my question here is not relevant anymore but I was asking about finding a way to revert to a asynchronous channel as a fail over for ActiveMQ. Therefore if MQ went down then I would by pass using MQ altogether. We now have a separate active MQ instance as a failover server so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it using `failover` mechanism:

```
<channel id="input">
  <dispatcher load-balancer="none"/>
</channel>

<service-activator input-channel="input" order="1"/>

<service-activator input-channel="input" order="2"/>
```

In this case the first `<service-activator>` will be always invoked first.
And the second one only if the first will fail.

The `failover` is `true` by default.

Comment: Only 3 years late ;) Moved on using Spring integration with RabbitMQ these days.